# I want to add some Javascript code to a webpage which can log all the network requests and responses made by the webpage when a user interacts with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, networking

For example, I have an email site like gmail and when a user clicks on a particular email, gmail will try to fetch the email from the gmail server. I want to log this request made by the client to the server and also the response of the server. Is there a way to do this using Javascript embedded in the webpage?

Comment: Why not just open the network tab of the browser?

Comment: I actually want to send these logs to the server so that we can count the number of  failed requests. Just want to use this for telemetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to log all requests/responses from client webpage to console, you can use javascript `Proxy` to mock the XMLHttpRequest.

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations

See [example](https://jsbin.com/futopicika/edit?html,js,console,output) here

Comment: Thank you very much, @Juky :)